# git svn clone fails with HTTP path not found on moved svn trunk

Tags: git-svn

I'm using git svn to access an svn repository. The svn repository was recently re-organised, with the trunk and a branch being swapped around i.e. trunk was moved to branches/old-trunk, and branches/foobar was moved to trunk.

Running `svn co http://path/to/svn/trunk` works fine on the new trunk, and I can add, update, and commit files without any problems.

However, when I do `git svn clone http://path/to/svn --stdlayout` I get the following error:

> HTTP Path Not Found: The path was not part of a repository: PROPFIND request failed on '/': '/' path not found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 2299

Does anyone know how to get git svn working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was being caused by accessing the svn repo from behind a proxy.

As well as my machine-wide proxy settings, I'd also got a `http-proxy-host` set in my `~/.subversion/servers` file under the `[global]` section, and the two settings seemed to be getting in each others way.

I commented out the `http-proxy-host` settings and was able to run `git svn clone` without any further issues.

**TL;DR** user error